# Registring Kryo classes is not working

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kryo

I have the following code :

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyApp")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
new conf.registerKryoClasses(new Class<?>[]{
        Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable"),
        Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.io.Text")
    });
```

But I am bumping into the following error :

```
')' expected but '[' found.
[error]                 new conf.registerKryoClasses(new Class<?>[]{
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing Scala and Java. In Scala, you can define an `Array[Class[_]]` (instead of a `Class<?>[]`):

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
            .setAppName("MyApp")
            .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
            .registerKryoClasses(Array[Class[_]](
              Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable"),
              Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.io.Text")
            ));

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

We can even do a little better. In order not to get our classes wrong using string literals, we can actually utilize the classes and use `classOf` to get their class type:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

val conf = new SparkConf()
            .setAppName("MyApp")
            .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
            .registerKryoClasses(Array[Class[_]](
              classOf[LongWritable],
              classOf[Test],
            ))

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Comment: Does this actually work ? Last time I have tried it with 1.5 it had no effect. I had to write a Java class in which I register my classes Kryo and then use the class as my serializer.

Comment: @eliasah I use Spark 1.6.1 and registering kryo classes like that works for me.

Comment: It's not a critic. Just a humble question ! :)

Comment: @eliasah I know I know :) Didn't mean to sound hostile :P

Comment: Me neither. I think we are both on the same page. (I follow your answers closely ;-) )